# Two request at same route emberjs 2

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

This is my scenario.

1. User input a zipcode and name location
2. Load data from a API which a payload that contains a location list
3. Show the location list for the user pick the right one.
4. Then bind data to complete registration and submit registration

First I tried a modal as component. After I see this is incorrect, then I moved to ember-data and do this on the route. I create a ember-data for location list (which be a component) and other for register values. I create the adapter and a serializer. So I completely lost what do next. How I do this, using a ember-data to search places(a GET) and a registration(POST) on the API?

Comment: your question details are not clear, `Two request at same route emberjs` that all you want to achieve ?

Comment: So two request is cause a get request and post request to a API. Sorry for my english I'm not a native. Its a form, for exemplo how od a form when first validate the email field in server and after that send the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have to make multiple requests at the same time you do

```
Ember.RSVP.all([
  $.ajax(...),
  this.store.findAll('person'),
  ...
]).then(function([result1, result2, result3 ]){
 console.log('all requests finished');
})
```

if you want sequential request (one after another) you simply chain them

```
$.ajax(...).then((ajaxResult) => { 
 return this.store.findAll('person')
}).then((person)=>{
 ....
}).then(function(){
 console.log('all requests finished')
})
```

Comment: It's not a sequence. I need know how I deal if two actions when one is dependent to a another after the use interaction.

Comment: it is a sequence. You have it as a sequential list in your question. One item happens after another - sequence

Comment: See you understand me, or I make a mess here, after the first loaded data(location info), I've a need a confirmation from user(will be a click) and send registration form after the click in submit button. So how this code will work, without actions listed in a route?